# Shortcut to find where opened tab / file is placed in project structure view in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ Idea 13 I have opened tab with file i.e. `file.js` - how I can quickly navigate to this file location in Project structure view?

I can use **Copy Path** but then I must paste it somewhere and the same with **Open in explorer** option.

I want to do this quickly in IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>
or
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>